# A field having higher Witt vectors as completions

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, fields

Given a finite field $F$ there is a unique (up to isomorphism) absolutely unramified complete DVR $W(F)$ of mixed characteristic that has $F$ as its residue field.

Fix a positive integer $n$. Does there exist a field that has a set of ultrametric absolute values $\{v_p\}$ indexed by the positive prime numbers such that the completion at $v_p$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Frac}(W(\mathbb{F}_{p^n}))$ as a valued field?

For $n=1$ an example of such a field is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 6):

$\mathbb Q(X)$ works for all $n$ simultaneously.

To do this, we just have to write down a homomorphism $\mathbb Q(X) \to \operatorname{Frac}(W (\mathbb F_{p^n}))$ with dense image, which we can do easily by sending $X$ to random element of $W (\mathbb F_{p^n})$. Then the pullback of the valuation of  $\operatorname{Frac}(W (\mathbb F_{p^n}))$ is a valuation of $\mathbb Q(X)$, and its completion is $ \operatorname{Frac}(W (\mathbb F_{p^n}))$